# Magento: what is table eav_entity for?

Tags: magento

I know EAV logic and I know what is eav_entity_attribute for. (about eav_entity_* - the same).
But I'm not clear about table eav_entity. It is always empty.

Could someone give some comments please.
I would be glad to get any assumption.

Google gives nothing on this question, as usual)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing a grep of the Community Edition code, the only time eav_entity is mentioned is in the config file (/app/core/code/Mage/Eav/etc/config.xml) and in the database setup files (/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/sql/eav_setup/mysql4-install-0.7.0.php).

To me this says that it was put in just before a release and then never actually used. The devs possibly decided to go with a slightly different way of storing the data...

Comment: Yep, it seems so...at the same time eav_entity_[datatime/decimal/int/store/text] are empty too. eav_entity_attribute and eav_entity_type doesn't, because they are part of EAV model. But what about the others (datatime/decimal/int/store/text)? Could be it is also not actually?

Comment: From what I can see, they look to have been created at the same time...and not used either

Answer (score 0):

I expected to see all records of all entities in the table `eav_entity`. But I see that Magento has created separate tables for each of the 8 entities `( customer, customer_address, category, product, order, invoice, shipment, creditmemo)` with the following table names `( customer_entity, customer_address_entity, catalog_category_entity, catalog_product_entity, sales_flat_order, sales_flat_invoice, sales_flat_shipment, sales_flat_creditmemo)`. So `eav_entity` table is empty and you get data for entities directly from their respective tables.. Some level of de-EAVing the database design :-)